# Sign Firefox extensions

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

We have two Firefox extensions - first for Mac and second for Windows. Extension for Mac is distributed through addons.mozilla.org site but extension for Windows through our own installer app.They do the same things but have a different code. They also have an identical UUID. 
   We did not have any problem before but recently Mozilla asked to sign all extensions. Unfortunatelly, if I try to sign the extension for Windows(distributed throug our installer) then I get "Duplicate UUID" error.

Is there any way to avoid it without changing UUID? For example, can I submit 2 versions as one app? If not, what happened if I change UUID? Will our users have any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code can be compiled into ONE addon, ie separate the sections that differ into individual files and import those based on OS, then the 2 addons can be merged and uploaded to Mozilla as one addon.

On the other hand if the codes are so radically different that they can not be merged, you would need to use different UUID.

I haven't come across many addons that are so OS specific that could not be made to work on other OSes.